# How to both center and auto-scale an image?

Tags: html, css, scaling, centering

Probably two of the most common problems with CSS layouting:

1. Centering both horizontally and vertically.
2. Auto-scaling images to the viewport size (maintaining the aspect ratio and not overflowing vertically or horizontally).

Individually, there are good solutions for both:

1. Use `display: table` on the outer container element and `display: table-cell`, `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` on the inner.
2. Use `max-height: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` on the `img` element.

[But combining both only does the centering](http://jsfiddle.net/jnkV6/), even when using `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` on all elements surrounding the `img`.

How can I achieve both targets at the same time without succumbing to hard-coded height and width values or JavaScript?

Comment: To be clear: you want the image to be horizontally and vertically centered (#1), you want either the edges of the image to touch the sides of the browser window, or the top/bottom of the image to touch the top/bottom of the window, _and you want the aspect ratio of the image to be maintained_?

Comment: "Auto-scaling images to viewport size." Do you mean, stretching the image to complete fill the viewport?

Comment: I want it to scale maintaining the aspect ratio, so that either the left/right or the top/bottom of the image touches the browser window if the original size is greater than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnkV6/1/)

Basically the image needs to take 100% of the height and width of the size of it's container. If you set a different size for the container it will be smaller. In the fiddle you can easily see it scale to the width, but since the height of the fiddle is slightly more fixed it's harder to tell.

Comment: I suspect that the OP wants the aspect ratio of the original image maintained.

Comment: Maybe. That would be good to know. I'm assuming this is for multiple screen sizes like mobile devices.

Comment: I want it to scale maintaining the aspect ratio, so that either the left/right or the top/bottom of the image touches the browser window if the original size is greater than the viewport.

Comment: just add width 100%, then the ratio will stay the same. http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/. Alternatively you canuse css3 background-sizing: cover/contain

Comment: @thepriebe, @Yannik Schall: With `width: 100%` the image vertically overflows the window.

Comment: @Legate Ok, here you go then. Switch to 100% height instead. http://jsfiddle.net/jnkV6/4/

Comment: @thepriebe: Overflows horizontally with a small-width window. I want it to not overflow either vertically or horizontally.

Comment: What's the smallest resolution you're shooting for?

Comment: @thepriebe: Where are you going with that question? I guess the smallest possible resolution is 1x1 px.

Comment: Ok, well this will work in everything >=IE9. If that's not a problem, then cool. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnkV6/5/)

Comment: IE incompatibility is not a problem. It's neat, thanks for that. Though it has still one problem left: The image scales over the original size.

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case I think you'll have to have something (php, js, etc) to figure out the actual size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of this but when you say 100% of anything, the parent's dimensions must be fixed or should lead back to a fixed size. Try giving width: SOMEINTpx; heigh: SOMEINTpx; in outer container.

Answer (score 0):

You can set image like background and try this:

```
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover; /*or contain*/
```